# Scrolling issue - Android Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I seem to be having an issue getting my app to scroll fully. I think there is an issue with the linear layout but would like your help to solve this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.app.aks.fragments.ThreeFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

//// some image and text views //////

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The window only scrolls partially and not all the way to the bottom....Suggestions?

Comment: will you please share the problematic screen shot ?

Comment: I am not sure how to show you this in a screen shot - best way I can describe it is that the page only scrolls half way down and then stops (even though there is content still to be viewed)

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivity.java`
Or whereever you are using/initializing these views.

Try this for all the textviews/image views. which are nested inside.

```
view.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct child of ScrollView should be another layout that supports multiple children, such as RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this and still a no-go.... best way I can describe it is that the page only scrolls half way down and then stops (even though there is content still to be viewed). Added android:fillViewport="true" to scrollview and no go there too..

Comment: Try making the layout-height "wrap content"

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: Nope, that did not fix it